# Knex.js changing Date in a column when other column is updated

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I'm using knex.js to work with SQL queries. I have a table with opt in information for example

```
{
 market_opt_in: 1
 market_opt_in_date: 2018-02-15 15:51:45
 message_opt_in: 0
 message_opt_in_date: 2018-02-15 15:51:45
 ...
}
```

and so on.

Is it possible to change date when individual opt_in is changed? So it would be like

```
{
 market_opt_in: 1
 market_opt_in_date: 2018-02-15 15:51:45
 message_opt_in: 1 // when this row updated
 message_opt_in_date: 2018-02-20 11:12:13 // date updates as well
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easier to implement with objection.js which is built on top of knex and has hooks for modifying data before insert / update.

With knex probably easiest way to support that would be to write separate helper function for updating that table, which always also sets the date in your case.

Another way would be to write event handler to knex.on('start', ...) event, look into query builder internals and if you find out from there that message_opt_in is updated you can add also update for message_opt_in_date column.

Anyways, I wouldn't suggest the 3rd way, since it may break when knex is updated.